# How to check input devices are in the same physical device?

Tags: linux, input

Because some input devices like gamepads may introduce several virtual devices like joystick+mouse+keyboard, i need to group them in my application to make sure it's the same gamepad. I can't find a reliable way in Linux to identify such cases. USB has uniq field often called also as serial number, but i found that:

1. most devices have it empty.
2. many cheap/DIY devices misuse this field by filling it with static data for all physical devices, so once grouped - all gamepads will look like one although they physically separate.

So obviously this field is not reliable. Comparing by name is also unreliable as several same input devices will be grouped.

So i need a reliable way to detect if /dev/input/event0 and /dev/input/event1 are physically the same device or not.

Comment: I don't think that a USB gadget can appear as multiple _devices_, but yes it can have multiple _configurations_ and _interfaces_. Unless that device is implementing itself a USB hub. You can easily pick the whole tree apart from [`/sys/bus/usb/devices/bus-port...port:config.interface`](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6)

Comment: Try `ls /dev/input/by-path`

Comment: All USB and PCI devices have a physical path in the /sys filesystem

Comment: I'm not talking about devices having USB hub inside. So only virtual devices (devices here are items in /dev, so from app view they are completely abstracted from real devices) as part of a single physical device are subject of topic. Configurations/Interfaces are not applicable when you work with /dev/input/eventX device.
USB device tree is not so helpful as it's hard to tell where to stop when you travel up to the root. It's too cryptic way to detect.

Comment: Key question is to tell /dev/input/event1 and /dev/input/event2 are part of the same joystick/gamepad or not, so it means even to travel in USB tree i need to know what exactly eventX it maps to. User may plug 2 or more same joysticks, so matching by VID/PID won't work.

Comment: i see useful pattern in /dev/input/by-path, so probably it can be used to group the virtual devices. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: unfortunately BT paired gamepads aren't displayed in /dev/input/by-path, although present as /dev/input/eventX.. So question is still open.